# Method in a loop not looping - Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, loops, methods

```
def playmany
    puts "Please enter in how many games you want to play"
    games_to_play = gets.chomp.to_i
    games_to_play.times do
        puts "\n"
        rules
    end
end
```

(Absolute ruby noob so apologies in advance if I'm using terms wrong)

I want this to repeat the method 'rules' but it only returns once and then breaks. Is there a way for the 'rules' method to be executed the amount of times the user specifies?

This is what 'rules' contains, I don't know if it's something in the 'playmany' method or the 'rules' method.

```
def rules
case player = rand(1..3)
    when player = 1
        player = "scissors"
        puts "Player choses: " + player
    when player = 2
        player = "paper"
        puts "Player choses: " + player
    when player = 3
        player = "rock"
        puts "Player choses: " + player
    end
case computer = rand(1..3)
    when computer = 1
        computer ="scissors"
        puts "Computer choses: " + computer
    when computer = 2
        computer ="paper"
        puts "Computer choses: " + computer
    when computer = 3
        computer = "rock"
        puts "Computer choses: " + computer
    end
case player
    when player = "scissors"
        if computer == "rock"
            puts "Player loses"
            $computertally += 1
            main_menu
        elsif computer == "scissors"
            puts "Computer and player tie"
            $tiecount += 1
            main_menu
        else
            puts "Player wins"
            $playertally += 1
            main_menu
        end
when player = "rock"
    if computer == "rock"
        puts "Computer and player ties"
        $tiecount += 1
        main_menu
    elsif computer == "scissors"
        puts "Player wins"
        $playertally += 1
        main_menu
    else
        puts "Player loses"
        $computertally += 1
        main_menu
    end
when player = "paper"
    if computer == "rock"
        puts "Player wins"
        $playertally += 1
        main_menu
    elsif computer == "scissors"
        puts "Player loses"
        $computertally += 1
        main_menu
    else
        puts "Computer and player tie"
        $tiecount += 1
        main_menu
    end
end
end
```

Update: The main_menu is this

```
puts "Welcome to rock, paper, scissors" 
puts "--------------------------------"
puts "\n"
puts "What do you want to do?"
puts "-- Type 'play' to have a turn"
puts "-- Type 'playmany' to play multiple games"
puts "-- Type 'score' to see the current scoreboard"
puts "-- Type 'exit' to exit"
def main_menu
case gets.chomp.downcase
    when "play"
        rules
    when "score"
        puts "\n"
        puts "Computer has won #{$computertally} games"
        puts "Player has won #{$playertally} games"
        puts "A tie has occured #{$tiecount} times"
        puts "\n"
        main_menu
    when "exit"
        exit
    when "playmany"
        playmany
    else
        puts "Error with selection, please try again"
        main_menu
    end
end
```

Comment: What does the `main_menu` method do?  That could be the source of your problem.

Comment: what's in `main_menu`?

Comment: `when player = 1` should be `when player == 1`, etc. You don't have to assign it in the `case` statement, though, since you overwrite it anyway. `case rand(1..3)`...`when 1`.... `when 2`....

Comment: Post your error message.  Your loop is ok.

Comment: The console just logs one instance of the `rules` method. I've updated the question to include the `main_menu` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question should properly be closed because SO is not here to debug your code. But since this is your first question, I will instead make a brief answer. Redefine `#rules` method as follows:

```
def rules
  puts "Hi, I'm looping!"
end
```

Now, if you call your `#playmany` method, you will see that `#rules` method actually *is* looping, but has a problem(s) in it. Think about what your method `rules` is supposed to do, try to write tests for it, and try to modify your method to fulfill the test expectations.

Comment: I'm not asking SO to debug my code, sorry if it appears that way. You're right, it was an issue within rules, it was trying to going back to main_menu causing the loop to break.

Comment: @Pan7h3r, sorry dude, but that's exactly what you did =). It is very unlikely that this answer will be helpful to any other reader except you. Big programmers write tests to make sure that every method does what it should. Debugging then becomes easier. In the context of testing, my redefined `#rules` method would be called a mock method to prove that your `#playmany` method was correct.

Comment: You're right, this question wouldn't really help many people, I'll keep that in mind next time I ask a question on SO :)

Answer (score 1):

On the `main_menu` options, are you actually entering "exit" ?

Exit really does exit the program.

Try replacing

```
when "exit"
exit
```

with

```
when "exit"
return
```

`return` will exit the main_menu method and allow your program to continue with subsequent steps, including the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `return`! In this instance I did actually want `exit` to exit the program, but in other areas of my code using `return` would be very useful.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, `exit` is a typical begginner's command, along with `eval` and devfining lambdas instead of object methods =).

Comment: @BorisStitnicky ha! :)

Answer (score 0):

hard to tell from this, but make sure you're indenting your code so it's easy to read and that all of your loops and conditionals conclude with and 'end' statement.

Also, try calling rules as follows - "rules()"

Comment: Putting empty parens on a method call doesn't do anything.